# How do I get flashvars in Firefox using object embed tag only to work?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, firefox, embed, flashvars

I am trying to generate an `<object>` tag only embed code and cannot get Firefox to pass Flash along the FlashVars values. This seems to work everyplace else that I've tried it but fails in Firefox. Here is a sample of the embed that I'm using:

`<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=10,0,0,0" width="550" height="400" id="Main" align="middle" data="Main.swf">
 <param name="movie" value="Main.swf" />
 <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
 <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
 <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
 <param name="quality" value="high" />
 <param name="menu" value="false" />
 <param name="FlashVars" value="foo=1" />
</object>`

Please note that the Flash experience does show up in Firefox but when I do traces and actually run the application this fails to read the values. This has had me scratching my head for a day and I'm pretty stumped. If anyone has any guidance on this it would relly be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried the timeing trick, you've had two answers supporting the theory, mine and mattias's. I've often been in the situation where flash vars don't come through and its pretty much always been because i've accessed them either on the first frame, or within actionscript before the flash player has had a chance to register them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have you tried

```
<param name="movie" value="Main.swf?foo=1" />
```

An 'oldschool' way of passing parameters to the SWF.

Comment: What I would like to do is not have to pass the FlashVars twice in an embed. In the example you gave I would have to do this both in the param and in the data attribute of the object tag. In Firefox you use th data attribute so it knows where the SWF lives since it doesn't respect the param location reference. 

Not quite what I'm looking for but hanks for the suggestion, though.

Comment: is there a reason why you don't use something like swfobject?

Comment: SWFObject isn't always an option, and in my case I would like to not rely upon JavaScript where a straight embed will, theoretically, work. This may be one of those browser limitations which just keeps things from being as compact and clean as I like. This also would help for sharing an embed code rather than having an embed nested within an object tag.

Answer (score 1):

i just ran the following in Fx 3.6 and it works fine.  i'm not sure why your version isn't working.  it might have something to do with the invalid attributes.  this is housed within an XHTML strict document with doctype set.

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="movie.swf" width="100" height="100">
    <param name="movie" value="movie.swf" />
    <param name="salign" value="lt" />
    <param name="flashvars" value="foo=bar" />
</object>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you either have at least 5 frames on the time line before you access the properties. Or if in code wait a while. The issue is the player sometimes doesn't have the value on the first frame. Later they will be there.

Comment: This is why it will sometimes work but not always and will differ on browsers and machines.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that your Flash Player plugin in Firefox has a different version or takes a little more time getting the parameters into the swf. Try Making a delayed call with a timer or an ENTER_FRAME listener to see if your parameters is set with a delay.

```
private function checkProgress(event : TimerEvent) : void
{
    // check if loaderInfo.parameters is set
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i use this embed (and yes, it contains embed tag) for my invisible mp3 player and it warks everywhere:

```
<object style="position:fixed" id="1pixPlayer" width="1" height="1" classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000">
<param value="transparent" name="wmode">
<param value="1pxMp3.swf" name="movie">
<param value="always" name="allowScriptAccess">
<param name="flashvars" value="id=1&amp;var=val&amp;var1=val1">
<embed name="1pixPlayer" width="1" height="1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" wmode="transparent" allowscriptaccess="always" src="1pxMp3.swf" flashvars="id=1&amp;var=val&amp;var1=val1"></object>
```

Comment: This example doesn't contain any parameters being passed to it, and as you mentioned also employs the embed tag I'm trying to avoid using. Yes, it will work but isn't quite what I was looking for really.

Comment: @Liam added flasvars to my answer. however i don't know a way to avoid embed in FF

Answer (score 0):

For Fire Fox use EMBED TAG under Object Tag as